# Android app which automatically compresses videos in background to save disk space

Tags: android, automation, video-editing

I'm searching for an app that converts or compresses my videos in another format without or with minimal quality loss to save disk space.

It should compress 1080p, 60fps, or 4K videos.

The app should automatically compress the videos while the phone is loading overnight.

Comment: Youtube's compression encoding is pretty powerful.you can upload your 4K videos and download after that.It makes the size really small.

Comment: I don't want to share my private videos on youtube

Comment: Their's an only me option available too on that ll make your videos private no one besides you can see them.